vue-i18n how to use mergeLocaleMessage?
I m trying to upgrade my vue 2.x app to vue 3.x. I updated the vue-i18n plugin and the code like this
const vueI18N = createI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: {
        en: messagesEn,
        de: messagesDe,
    },
});

vueI18N.mergeLocaleMessage('en', customStringsEn);
vueI18N.mergeLocaleMessage('de', customStringsDe);
vueI18N.mergeLocaleMessage('en', wikiLinksEn);
vueI18N.mergeLocaleMessage('de', wikiLinksDe);

export default vueI18N;

but its throwing error:
Property 'mergeLocaleMessage' does not exist on type 'I18n<{

How to use mergeLocaleMessage feature in v9 of vue-i18n?

vueI18N.global.mergeLocaleMessage('en', customStringsEn);
